# Problems with rails helper link_to concerning class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having difficulties with rails. In fact, I wrote these lines :

```
<%= link_to :controller => "offers", :action => "get_offer", :offer_slug => offer.friendly_id, {:class => "media"} do %>
```

.
.
.

```
<% end %>
```

My problem is that everything that is inside link_to is getting the css effects of a hyperlink (no padding, gets underlined when hover), instead of custom properties.

It's like the :class property isn't being taken into account.

Just in case, here's the full part :

```
 <<%= link_to :controller => "offers", :action => "get_offer", :offer_slug => offer.friendly_id, {:class => "media"} do %>

                        <li id="<%= offer.id %>" class="media" style="border: 1px solid #696969">
                          <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:0px; font-size:12px; text-align:center; margin-right:10px;">

                            <% if offer.subcategory.nil? %>
                                <img class="media-object" src="<%= asset_path "other-icon.png" %>" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                            <% elsif offer.subcategory.category.icon.empty? %>

                            <% else %>
                                <img src="<%= asset_path offer.subcategory.category.icon %>" style="margin-bottom:5px; width:110px;">
                            <% end %>

                            <br/>

                            <% if offer.subcategory.present? %>
                                <b><%= offer.subcategory.category.name %></b><br/> <%= offer.subcategory.name %>
                            <% else %>
                                <b>Autres</b><br/> <%= offer.subcategory_other %>
                            <% end %>

                          </div>

                          <div class="media-body">
                            <!--Titre annonce + type contrat-->

                            <div style="text-align:right; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                              <% if offer.id >= @new_limit %>
                                  <span class="label label-warning">New</span>
                              <% end %>
                              <span class="label label-success"><%= (offer.max_price * 0.85).ceil %> euros</span>
                              <span class="label label-success" style="background-color: grey"><%= (offer.customer_objective) %>
                                succès </span>
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="media-heading">
                              <%= raw(offer.name) %>
                            </h4>


                            <p>
                              <% if offer.description %>
                                  <%= offer.description.split[0..60].join(" ") %>

                                  <% if offer.description.split[0..60].count >= 59 %>
                                  <% end %>

                              <% end %>
                            </p>

                            <% if offer.company_context.present? %>
                                <p>
                                  <%= offer.company_context.split[0..60].join(" ") %>
                                  <% if offer.company_context.split[0..60].count >= 59 %>
                                  <% end %>
                                </p>
                            <% end %>

                          </div>

                          <div class="offer-tags">
                            <% offer.offer_tags.each do |offer_tag| %>
                                <span class="badge"><%= offer_tag.tag.name %></span>
                            <% end %>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, on your first line, I imagine this would cause a syntax error:  `<<%= link_to :controller ...` . Should just be `<%= link_to :controller ...` Maybe it's just a copy/paste thing here, not in your actual file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the class in curly braces:

```
<%= link_to :controller => "offers", :action => "get_offer", :offer_slug => offer.friendly_id, { :class => "media" } %>
```

The Rails `link_to` helper is pretty flexible and allows a few different call signatures, which can lead to confusion.  You are needing this one:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Without the wrapping braces, Rails is not clear that `:class` is in fact an HTML option.

Docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).  I should mention I also dropped your trailing `do` which implied a block that didn't seem to be there (nor was it needed).

**UPDATE**

I did not understand that the block was intended as the link body.  In that case, the right call signature would be:

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

So, your body is fine, but in your `link_to`, you want to group the URL options, followed by the HTML options.  Plus I think you may need parentheses around the whole call for it to work correctly:

```
<%= link_to({ :controller => "offers", :action => "get_offer", :offer_slug => offer.friendly_id }, { :class => "media" }) do %>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting =>
...ly_id, { :class => "media" } do @output_buffer.safe_append='

Comment: @Francky - can you add an update to your post with your updated code based on my suggestion?  If there is a need for the `do` block, please post that code as well, through to the `<% end %>`.

Comment: I've just done it, with the block, and your suggestion.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `do` block?  Your URL options all appear to be included on `link_to` line.  If that defines the link, remove the do (and end).  Otherwise, if all of that stuff is needed, you'll need to move your URL options into the block as there is no call signature with URL options, HTML options and a &block.  Refer to the doc link in my answer.

Comment: The purpose of the do is to make all the <li> inside it cliquable. So that all the box is turned into an hyperlink.

Comment: So basically, what comes after the do corresponds to all the body in your example : link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})